# How do I use TypeScript within Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am looking to use *TypeScript* within Visual Studio 2013. For some reason, however, I cannot create a project. Instead, Visual Studio only allows me to be directed to a web page which tells me to install a plugin.

After I've installed the plugin, as well as rebooting my computer a few times; still no dice.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstall *all* typescript items from *Programs and Features* in your control panel. Then reinstall this plugin : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Make sure visual studio is closed throughout uninstall/install process. After the install start visual studio.

Comment: ^ this. Plus, in my case, I additionally had to Tools --> Import and Export Settings... --> Reset all settings.