# Visual Studio 2013 and Typescript installation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am having the exact same problem as in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433592/how-do-i-use-typescript-within-visual-studio-2013) and I have done the exact steps in the featured answer, including the comment at the end of the answer, and I still cannot create a Typescript project nor add a Typescript file to an existing project because the template does not exist.

Please I really need to get this to work I need help. I am using Visual Studio Premium 2013.

**UPDATE: This issue was pre - update 2 release. With this update installed the issue does not exist any more.**

Comment: Upgrade to Release 2 of Visual Studio 2013. All TypeScript support is now fully integrated. Note: The TypeScript templates only appear to be available in some project types, so what project type are you creating?

Comment: add this as the answer and accept it :3