# Typescript Issues in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I am new to typescript, and I am working through the Angular tutorial for my job in Visual studio 2013, which I am also new to. The issue is that Visual Studio seems to think I intend on using another language (from the errors I would guess C) and marks up everything with red dots and squiggly underlines, making it very difficult/just plain annoying to read and write code.

All the code is correct and runs, I am following a tutorial so most of it is literally copied and pasted.

Comment: Visual studio intellisense should handle that based on the type of the file - maybe a silly question but are you definitely pasting into a .ts file?

Comment: Other than that I'd say maybe a plugin is required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433592/how-do-i-use-typescript-within-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andy, the visual studio 2013 TS plugin worked for me. It can be found here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48739